# locklift error while deploying smart contract on venom network: "Error: Giver has empty contract state, check the giver address",

Tags: smartcontracts, ton, venom

I was trying to deploy my smart contract on the venom devnet blockchain with this `jrpc` URL

[jrpc url](https://jrpc-devnet.venom.foundation/)

but I got an error with this message

`Error("Giver has empty contract state, check the giver address");`

> ```
> Users/sam/code/Web3/venomDAO/node_modules/locklift/internal/giver/index.js:24
> throw new Error("Giver has empty contract state, check the giver address");
>               ^
> Error: Giver has empty contract state, check the giver address
> at getGiver (/Users/sam/code/Web3/venomDAO/node_modules/locklift/internal/giver/index.js:24:15)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at Function.setup (/Users/sam/code/Web3/venomDAO/node_modules/locklift/index.js:154:41)
> at initLockliftStep (/Users/sam/code/Web3/venomDAO/node_modules/locklift/internal/cli/steps/initLocklift.js:8:23)
> at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/sam/code/Web3/venomDAO/node_modules/locklift/internal/cli/commands/run.js:36:5)
> ```

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Running on testnet. My account has enough balance. No clues on how to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, such an error happens, when there are no tokens on the giver balance

Comment: yes actually I was deploying on the wrong network that I didn't have enough balance on 
Thanks

Comment: Any other ideas on why this problem could happen? I have enough balance and I'm on the correct network.

Comment: can you post locklift connection string in locklift.config.tsl
for example you are using a network like this 
```npx locklift run script/1.ts -n testnet```
that testnet in the command above will point  a connection string in locklift.config.ts 
you should check your balance in that network

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who are using `locklift init` (like venom youtube tutorial) it configures the endpoint for Venom devnet. Which is not the Venom testnet.
So, go into your `locklift.config.ts` and change

```js
const VENOM_TESTNET_ENDPOINT = process.env.VENOM_TESTNET_ENDPOINT || "https://jrpc-testnet.venom.foundation/rpc";
const VENOM_TESTNET_TRACE_ENDPOINT =
  process.env.VENOM_TESTNET_TRACE_ENDPOINT || "https://gql-testnet.venom.foundation/graphql";
```

Edit: this didn't let me deploy the contract. So I had to use devnet instead. And get tokens through `https://faucet.venom.network/`.